# Why java ThreadPoolExecutor kill thread when RuntimeException occurs?

Tags: java, concurrency

Why the unhanded exception is rethrown in worker when calling execute method ? As result new Thread will be created on next execution to maximize threads count

Comment: Could you show us an example? (Put it *in the question*, please)

Comment: Feel free to open code and take a look yourself

Comment: Post the relevant portions of the code here, please.

Comment: Another instance of a high-rep user (with five gold badges) not knowing how to use the site.

Comment: It doesnt 'kill the thread'. The thread kills itself, because the Runnable threw an uncaught exception. It isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why java ThreadPoolExecutor kill thread when RuntimeException occurs?

I can only guess that the reason why `ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(...)` has the thread call `runnable.run()` *directly* and not wrap it in a `FutureTask` is so you would not incur the overhead of the `FutureTask` if you didn't care about the result.

If your thread throws a `RuntimeException`, which is hopefully a rare thing, and there is no mechanism to return the exception to the caller then why pay for the wrapping class?  So worst case, the thread is killed and will be reaped and restarted by the thread-pool.

Comment: It does not kill it on submit. Runnable for execute method is not wrapped in FutureTask

Comment: I don't understand @aauser.  Your _task_ will be killed but the thread will continue to run and execute the next job in the thread-pool unless it has been shutdown.

Comment: When task is submitted via "execute" method it is not wrapped via FutureTask. If task is submitted via "submit" it is wrapped via FutureTask and exception is handled. You can make simple test, create SingleThreadedExecutor, execute Runnable, log threadId, throw Exception, execute another Runnable, compare ThreadId

Comment: Huh.  Never appreciated that before @aauser.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to handle exception properly. Exception can't be propagated to caller thread and can't be simply swallowed.

Unhandled exception is thrown in thread is delegated to `ThreadGroup.uncaughtException` method, which prints output to `System.err.print`, until desired behavior is overridden for `ThreadGroup`.

So this is expected behavior, it can be compared with throwing unhanded exception in main method. In this case, JVM terminates execution and prints exception to the output.

But I'm not sure, why `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not handle it itself, `ThreadPoolExecutor` can log it itself. Creating new `Thread` is not so cheap.

Maybe there is an assumption, that some resources (native, threadLocal, threadStack, etc) associated with `Thread` should be released.