# Why java ThreadPoolExecutor kill thread when RuntimeException occurs?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

It's the same as [Why java ThreadPoolExecutor kill thread when RuntimeException occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123533/why-java-threadpoolexecutor-kill-thread-when-runtimeexception-occurs) but there's no wide acceptable answer.

In the Worker's run method

```
/**
 * Main run loop
 */
public void run() {
    try {
        Runnable task = firstTask;
        firstTask = null;
        while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
            runTask(task);
            task = null;
        }
    } finally {
        workerDone(this);
    }
}
```

Why not simply catch RuntimeException in the while loop to let the worker keep looping?

ps: I'm using Java 6 on Mac. Java 8 makes some change but no difference with the mechanism.

Comment: catch the exception inside while loop....

Comment: I'd say it is one of those design-decisions that could as well have been done differently. Personally, I would guess it's simply not the worker's responsibility.

Comment: It doesnt 'kill the thread'. The thread kills itself, because the Runnable threw an uncaught exception. It isn't the same thing.